# Using Ruby on Rails, what is an efficient method of ordering separate users post_id's sequentially?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My domain structure is similar to this:

```
www.domain.com/:user_id/post/:post_id
i.e. www.domain.com/user1/post/1
```

I would like it to work where each user's post increments up the user's last :post_id, disregarding the actual ID of the database row, as multiple users posts will be stored there, like so:

```
www.domain.com/user1/post/1
www.domain.com/user1/post/2

www.domain.com/user2/post/1
www.domain.com/user2/post/2
```

I understand I will need a "secondary_id" column in the Post database and before committing a post to the database I will need to query the last post of the user to obtain that secondary_id to increment but I'm unsure where this logic would best reside in my app structure and what can I do to simplify/automate the process?

Also, how can I avoid race conditions on the secondary_id if this where implemented in a team environment where users could be submitting posts in between when another user has queried for the last secondary_id to increment and the second user would error out since the other user got to that secondary_id first?

Comment: Sounds as though you're looking to use a **composite primary key**. Perhaps something like this? https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys Alternatively, why not just store a second database column - something like `user_post_number`? (You could add a scoped uniqueness constraint here, too.) Then look up the records by this value instead of the `id`.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you're doing this, though... There are other ways to create "friendly URLs" that don't involve integers at all (e.g. use the post title), which would avoid this whole complexity.

Comment: I strongly agree with @TomLord, composite primary keys are a pain (I am currently working on a huge task to remove one from our DB, it's a pain, trust me), and also using a simple `user_post_number` (integer) indexed column would do the trick. But best of all, friendly URLs like `/user/1/post/12-slug-of-the-post-title` is much more readable AND helps your ranking in the search engines.

Comment: Look at the URL of *this* web page, for example! It's `/questions/48889279/using-ruby-on-rails-what-......`, not `users/523051/questions/52`.

Comment: i'm trying to mimick the stackoverflow method where /user1/post/:post_id/slug-here-is-irrelevant-and-changes-to-it-will-still-enable-old-urls-to-work

Comment: @chrickso The description of your question is **not** mimicking StackOverflow. As I just said, the `post_id` **is** the `post_id`, not some secondary counter.

Comment: tom, my question is "phase 1" of getting to a SO-style of utilizing both a post id and slug, but unlike SO that just increments an id of a "questions" DB, i can't be having user1 get post 1 and user2's next post is post 2.